# Are rectangles are trapezium

Tags: geometry

Rectangle by definition given as the quadrilateral in which opposite sides are equal and each angle is equal to 90 degree

Where as in case of trapezium any one pair of opposite sides is parallel.

Can we say rectangle as trapezium .

Comment: The rectangle *is* a trapezoid (or trapezium). A very particular case of trapezoid, which is both a right trapezoid *and* an isosceles trapezoid, but it *is* a trapezoid. All properties of trapezoids apply to rectangles as well (e.g. the area formula). For a visual breakdown/classification of the various quadrilaterals see for example the [Euler diagram of some types of simple quadrilaterals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral#/media/File:Euler_diagram_of_quadrilateral_types.svg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general by definition rectangles are not trapzeoids, only one pair of sides are parallel in a trapezoid. There are some definitions though which define parallelograms to be trapzeoids. It comes down to the definition given in class.

Comment: What is wrong with my question please point out

Comment: please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid

Comment: It comes down to the definition, some include parallelograms, some dont

Comment: Just visited as you said: it points out Under the inclusive definition, all parallelograms (including rhombuses, rectangles and squares) are trapezoids.

Comment: Yes exactly! It comes down to the definition you had in class. I think most definitions are exclusive though

Comment: Repost the answer with inclusive and exclusive so that I will accept your answer

Comment: @asddf `In general by definition rectangles are not trapzeoids` Would you mind quoting an authoritative source which says that rectangles are not trapezoids? The link to wikipedia you posted in a previous comment says exactly the opposite. In general, parallelograms, rectangles, rhombi and squares are all considered to be particular cases of trapezoids.

Comment: I was talking about personal experience, what i have seen so far myself. Maybe it was wrong for me to generalise.

Answer (score 0):

In a trapezium opposites angles are supplementary, one pair only parallel. Rectangle is a special case. Most of the time a trapezium is isosceles.

Comment: `In a trapezium opposites angles are supplementary` No, unless it's an isosceles trapezoid.

Comment: Yes, so i added *most of the time* it is an isosceles trapezoid. People go to this geometry to go away from either  sided parallelism but not willing to give up the central symmetry of the rectangle.